# My SQL Query is working on one date, but I want start date to end date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005

I have two tables:

**CheckInOut**

```
TR          BadgeNum    USERID      Dated                   Time                    CHECKTYPE
-------     ---------   ------    -----------------------  -----------------------  ----------
2337334     4           1         2018-04-01 00:00:00.000  2018-04-14 10:10:58.000      I
2337334     4           1         2018-04-01 00:00:00.000  2018-04-14 18:10:00.000      O
2337334     4           1         2018-04-02 00:00:00.000  2018-04-14 10:00:10.000      I
2337335     4           1         2018-04-02 00:00:00.000  2018-04-14 18:14:27.000      O
2337336     4           1         2018-04-03 00:00:00.000  2018-04-14 10:22:10.000      I
2337334     4           1         2018-04-03 00:00:00.000  2018-04-14 18:03:11.000      O
2337337     44          5         2018-04-01 00:00:00.000  2018-04-14 09:27:03.000      I
2337337     44          5         2018-04-01 00:00:00.000  2018-04-14 18:27:42.000      O
2337337     44          5         2018-04-02 00:00:00.000  2018-04-14 10:00:50.000      I
2337337     44          5         2018-04-02 00:00:00.000  2018-04-14 18:02:25.000      O
2337337     44          5         2018-04-03 00:00:00.000  2018-04-14 08:58:36.000      I
2337337     44          5         2018-04-03 00:00:00.000  2018-04-14 18:12:18.000      O
```

**UserInfo**

```
Tr     UserID    BadgeNumber     Name      
-----  -------   -----------  --------------
13652     44          5        SAMIA NAZ
13653     4           1        Waqar Yousufzai
```

I need to calculate presence hours for each day for each user. My below query is working fine for given day. But I need to calculate for a given range. How do I get expected result?

```
Select  isnull(max(ch.userid), 0)As 'ID' 
    ,isnull(max(ch.badgenum), 0)as 'Badge#' 
    ,isnull(max(convert(Char(10), ch.dated, 103)), '00:00')as 'Date'
    ,isnull(max(ui.name),'Empty')as 'Name'
    ,isnull(min(convert(VARCHAR(26), ch.time, 108)), '00:00')   as 'Time In'
    ,case when min(ch.time) = max(ch.time) then '' else isnull(max(convert(VARCHAR(26), ch.time, 108)), '00:00') end as 'TimeOut' 
    ,case when min(ch.time) = max(ch.time) then 'Absent' else 'Present' end as 'Status' 
    ,isnull(CONVERT(varchar(3),DATEDIFF(minute,min(ch.time), max(ch.time))/60) + ' hrs and ' +
           RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEDIFF(minute,min(ch.time),max(ch.time))%60),2)  + 'Min'  , 0) as 'Total Hrs'
    From CHECKINOUT ch left Join userinfo ui on ch.badgenum = ui.badgenumber
    Where ch.Dated between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-03' GROUP BY ch.badgenum
```

**Query result**

```
ID      Badge#  Date       Name             Time In     TimeOut     Status  Total Hrs
---     ------  ---------- ---------------  --------    ---------- -------- -----------------
4       1       03/04/2018 Waqar Yousufzai  11:33:34    18:24:23    Present 30 hrs and 14Min
82      3       03/04/2018 TANVEER ANSARI   09:37:14    19:18:22    Present 32 hrs and 37Min
13      4       03/04/2018                  07:19:26    09:30:17    Present 21 hrs and 49Min
44      5       03/04/2018 SAMIA NAZ        08:53:15    18:25:21    Present 33 hrs and 24Min
28      7       03/04/2018 Anees Ahmad      08:34:57    22:00:38    Present 61 hrs and 25Min
46      8       03/04/2018 Shazia - OT      08:10:41    16:15:05    Present 32 hrs and 01Min
```

**Expected result**

```
ID      Badge#  Date       Name             Time In     TimeOut     Status  Total Hrs
    ---     ------  ---------- ---------------  --------    ---------- -------- -----------------
    4       1       01/04/2018 Waqar Yousufzai  10:30:00    18:00:00    Present 7 hrs and 30Min
    4       1       02/04/2018 Waqar Yousufzai  10:30:00    18:00:00    Present 7 hrs and 30Min
    4       1       03/04/2018 Waqar Yousufzai  10:00:00    18:00:00    Present 8 hrs and 00Min
    44      5       01/04/2018 SAMIA            08:00:00    18:00:00    Present 10 hrs and 00Min
    44      5       02/04/2018 SAMIA            08:30:00    18:00:00    Present 9 hrs and 30Min
    44      5       03/04/2018 SAMIA            08:00:00    18:00:00    Present 10 hrs and 00Min
```

Comment: List `ch.Dated` in `group by` and `select`

Comment: Edit your question so that the values in your example and description actually match your query.  Then give example input and output data.  Then take out the irrelevant bits of code, concentrating on the minimal part of the question you're trying to explore.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: So rather then one result row per batchnum, you want one row per batchnum and day?

Comment: i am already Trying ' group by ch.Dated ' but its return some employees..

Comment: i want multiple rows of badgenum  by dated...
**ID**   **Badge#**   **Date**      **Name**   **Time In**   **TimeOut**
112           127        01/04/2018   Zafar             07:15               22:59
112           127        02/04/2018   Zafar             07:00               23:00
112           127        01/04/2018   Rose             08:00               16:00
112           127        02/04/2018   Rose             08:30               16:10
and etc

Comment: Providing sample data from what you got your result would be very helpful

Comment: dear @uzi   i am change my Questioning way.. and mention in Detail. with example...

Comment: Unfortunately your question is still unclear. You should provide not just expected output but some sample data from what you got that result. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49950941/update-a-table-by-joining-to-the-most-recent-record-of-another-table-that-meets). That is best way of providing sample data

Comment: i am already mentioned what data i got. **Result of One day** and **Result of more then one day**

Comment: That are results of execution of your query. We need the data that are **stored** in the tables. Without that we can't help you

Comment: i got this result using two tables. **UserInfo** and **CheckInOut**. mention in **My Storesd Data**

Comment: @Uzi i am give Detail to you. as per your requirement .....

Comment: I have edited your question, don't you mind? Old question was almost unreadable. Feel free to edit or revert back if I made any mistakes. What's the datatype of `time` column? I guess it should be time, but you have provided datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do aggregation on date value, it must be part of grouping. Get time out and time in using conditional aggregation. And count total hours worked. Your query should be something like:

```
select
    BadgeNum, USERID, Dated, Name
    , right('0' + cast(datediff(mi, [in], [out]) / 60 as varchar(10)), 2) + ':'
    + right('0' + cast(datediff(mi, [in], [out]) % 60 as varchar(10)), 2)
from (
    select
        ch.BadgeNum, ch.USERID, dated = cast(ch.Dated as date), ui.Name
        , [in] = min(case when ch.CHECKTYPE = 'I' then ch.Time end)
        , [out] = min(case when ch.CHECKTYPE = 'O' then ch.Time end)

    from
        CheckInOut ch
        left join UserInfo ui on ch.USERID = ui.badgenumber
    where
        ch.Dated >= '20180401'
        and ch.Dated < '20180404'
    group by ch.BadgeNum, ch.USERID, cast(ch.Dated as date), ui.Name
) t
```

Comment: Thank you sir....
there is some problems. you are using Checktype colum in your Example but i dont want to use CheckType columns.
i want to take time using Min() as 'In' and Max() as 'Out' operators.
and Show columns Time In and Time Out.

Comment: Without CheckType column you can't be sure what date you are getting. For example, for a user with only one entry in a day both `min` and `max` functions will return same value. And how do you know thats `In` or `Out`? But if you want to do as you said, just change aggregation functions as you need