# Update a table by joining to the most recent record of another table that meets some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to avoid the urge to use a loop for this solution and instead use a set-based operation.

I need to update each record in a table based on the most recent occurrence of a join to another table. My first thought was to join to the table that I need the "most recent date" from and group on the join conditions, but using `GROUP BY` with `UPDATE` is invalid.

Here's what I have so far. I have a feeling this will be solved with a CTE...

```
CREATE TABLE Part (
    Area            VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    SequenceNumber  INT         NOT NULL,
    DateAdded       DATETIME    NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Part VALUES
('A', 1, '2018-04-01'),
('A', 1, '2018-04-02'),
('A', 2, '2018-04-03'),
('A', 2, '2018-04-04'),
('B', 2, '2018-04-04'),
('B', 2, '2018-04-03'),
('B', 3, '2018-04-02'),
('B', 3, '2018-04-01');

DECLARE @Filters    TABLE
(
    Area            VARCHAR(10),
    StartingSeqNum  INT,
    StartTime       DATETIME 
);
INSERT INTO @Filters VALUES
('A', 2, NULL),
('B', 3, NULL);

-- Update each StartTime in @Filters with the most recent
-- DateAdded of the corresponding SequenceNumber in the Part table per Area.
UPDATE f
SET f.StartTime = MAX(p.DateAdded)
FROM
    @Filters f
    INNER JOIN Part p ON p.Area = f.Area
        AND p.SequenceNumber = f.StartingSeqNum
GROUP BY
    p.Area,
    p.SequenceNumber;
```

Based on the sample data above, the operation should populate the following values in `@Filters`:

```
('A', 2, '2018-04-04')
('B', 3, '2018-04-02')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use a CTE to do this, as so:

```
;with maxParts as
(
    select Area, SequenceNumber, MAX(dateadded) as maxDateAdded 
    from Part
    group by Area, SequenceNumber
)
UPDATE f
SET f.StartTime = p.maxDateAdded
from @Filters f
    inner join maxParts p 
        on f.Area = p.Area
        and f.StartingSeqNum = p.SequenceNumber
```

However, you can also rewrite the CTE as a subquery:

```
UPDATE f
SET f.StartTime = p.maxDateAdded
from @Filters f
    inner join (
            select Area, SequenceNumber, MAX(dateadded) as maxDateAdded 
            from Part
            group by Area, SequenceNumber
        ) p 
        on f.Area = p.Area
        and f.StartingSeqNum = p.SequenceNumber
```

The query plans for these should be identical - all the CTE really allows you is cleaner-looking queries and the ability to easily reuse that SELECT.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem!

Something to consider for future set-based work - if you can produce result set(s) using a `select` statement that get what you want, it's usually pretty easy to use those `select`s in subqueries or as CTEs.

Answer (score 1):

(a)

```
UPDATE Filters
       SET Filters.StartTime = (SELECT max(Part.DateAdded)
                                FROM Part
                                WHERE Part.Area = Filters.Area
                                      AND Part.SequenceNumber = Filters.StartingSeqNum)
       FROM @Filters Filters;
```

(b)

```
UPDATE Filters
       SET Filters.StartTime = X.StartTime
       FROM @Filters Filters
            INNER JOIN (SELECT max(Part.DateAdded) StartTime,
                               Part.Area,
                               Part.SequenceNumber
                               FROM Part
                               GROUP BY Part.Area,
                                        Part.SequenceNumber) X
                       ON X.Area = Filters.Area
                          AND X.SequenceNumber = Filters.StartingSeqNum;
```

Both, (a) and (b) should do what you want. I'm not sure whats better. Maybe (b) can reuse the subquery relation and therefore costs less overall.

Comment: Thanks for your help!